# Show articles of day Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got on my db the table "articles" with field "created_at" = "2018-02-11 01:22:03". How can I get only the links of the current day?

```
$articles = Article::where('status', 1)->take(5)->get();
return view("site.view", compact("articles"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$articles = Article::whereDate('created_at', today())->where('status', 1)->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works! And how can I count and put in other variable? $articles_count...

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso if you want to count results of this exact query, do this `$counted = $articles->count()`. This code will not create any additional query to DB.

Comment: But I have a problem, because I put 5 articles in first get... I want to do another query to count all links of day...

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso `$counted = Article::whereDate('created_at', today())->where('status', 1)->count();`

Comment: Thank you so much.